# Does Action run history move too when you transfer a Github repo to another organization?

Tags: github, github-actions

I have two Github organizations and I want to transfer a repo between them.
From the documentation this seems very straightforward, except I haven't found any documentation to indicate what happens to the Action run history.
Does that get transfered too?

Comment: Looks like the docs don't state that explicitly, so it might be faster to give it a try on a sample repo: create sample repo, create a trivial workflow, run it couple of times, then transfer the repo the way you plan to do for the real one.

Comment: Yeah, it's looking like that's what I'm going to have to do, I was hoping to avoid the hassle.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes - at least for us. Haven't found this documented anywhere but we've just transferred several repositories and their action run histories and logs were kept.